# Correcting skewed SVG rendering

Tags: web, svg

I have created a single jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vokoyisofo/edit?html,css,output

You can see four triangles rendering within one another. Each triangle is 10% smaller than the previous. The containing SVG is 300x300. I would expect everything to render out square but that doesn't happen. I assume there is some sort of screen stretching happening. The space between the bottom borders of each triangle looks much larger than the space between the top tips.

How do I correct for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance from the top vertex of the outer triangle to the top vertex of the next largest one is 30 units.

The distance from the right hand bottom corner vertex of the outer triangle to the right hand bottom corner vertex of the next largest one is not 30 units. It's √(30 * 30 + 30 * 30) units or approximately 42 units.

That's why the shape is only symmetrical in the vertical axis. It looks skewed because that's how you've defined it.

If you want it to be symmetrical you want the bottom vertices to go in by 30 units in the direction of the centre of the triangle which will mean that they decrease by 30 / √2 units in each of x and y